# sar + sar command failed to found folder under /var/log/sa

Tags: linux, rhel, sar

on our rhel Linux server we do the following in order to get info from sar command

but we get

```
sar
Cannot open /var/log/sa/sa31: No such file or directory
```

but we can see that only the following folders are exsist

```
ls /var/log/sa/
sa01  sa04  sa07  sa10  sa13  sa16  sa19  sa22  sa25  sa28  sar01  sar04  sar07  sar10  sar13  sar16  sar19  sar22  sar25  sar28
sa02  sa05  sa08  sa11  sa14  sa17  sa20  sa23  sa26  sa29  sar02  sar05  sar08  sar11  sar14  sar17  sar20  sar23  sar26  sar29
sa03  sa06  sa09  sa12  sa15  sa18  sa21  sa24  sa27  sa30  sar03  sar06  sar09  sar12  sar15  sar18  sar21  sar24  sar27  sar30
```

so why sar command complain about `sar31`?

how to avoid this problem ?

Comment: So there is no file `/var/log/sa/sa31` ?  What changed today ?

Comment: its typical rhel server no change as I know , and yes this is the real output from ls ( no sa31 folder )

Comment: Someone's edited the cron job which runs the `/usr/lib64/sa/sa1` collector to run on days 1-30 rather than 1-31 ?

Comment: I dont think so because I check that

Comment: cron died ?  Check the cron log, see if it's happily running cron jobs ?